# Parallel HDF5 C++ program that creates a group for each MPI process rank

Tags: c++, hdf5

I am trying to find a minimal example for opening and closing a HDF5 file in parallel using the MPIO driver in the C++ interface to HDF5, that creates a HDF5 Group for each MPI process rank and saves the file. [The parallel programming example given in the repo](https://bitbucket.hdfgroup.org/projects/HDFFV/repos/hdf5/browse/examples/ph5example.c) is not quite what I would call minimal, but I tried to use parts of that example, [together with the C++ API docs](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/h5group_8cpp-example.html) and the [simple C++ parallel HDF5 example set](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/misc-examples/#parallel).

This is what I came up with so far:

**Edit**: I have added a loop over MPI ranks to try and create the HDF5 groups in collective mode, the result is the same.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
#include "H5Cpp.h"
using namespace H5;
using namespace std; 

int main(void)
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL); 

    // Get the number of processes
    int size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    // Get the rank of the process
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    auto acc_tpl1 = H5Pcreate(H5P_FILE_ACCESS);
    /* set Parallel access with communicator */
    H5Pset_fapl_mpio(acc_tpl1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_INFO_NULL);

    // Creating the file with H5File stores only a single group with 4 MPI processes.
    auto testFile = H5File("test.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, acc_tpl1);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        std::stringstream ss; 
        ss << "/RANK_GROUP" << rank; 
        string rankGroup {ss.str()}; 
        // Create the rank group with testFile.
        if (! testFile.exists(rankGroup))
        {
            cout << rankGroup << endl; 
            testFile.createGroup(rankGroup);
        }
    }

    // Release the file-access template 
    H5Pclose(acc_tpl1);

    // Release the testFile 
    testFile.close();

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out [from the C++ API how to set the MPIO driver](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/class_h5_1_1_file_acc_prop_list.html).

Also, the groups are not written by every rank:

```
?> h5c++ test-mpi-group-creation.cpp  -o test-mpi-group-creation
?> mpirun -np 4 ./test-mpi-group-creation
/RANK_GROUP0
/RANK_GROUP1
/RANK_GROUP2
/RANK_GROUP3
?> h5ls -lr test.h5 
/                        Group
/RANK_GROUP1             Group
```

What do I need to change to have this minimal parallel example with groups running using the C++ API to hdf5?

Answer (score 3):

In HDF5, all the "metadata" must be created by all ranks in collective mode. That is: every processor will open the file, create all groups, create all datasets. Then, you can write to the specified datasets individually. Note that in the case of extendable datasets the resizing must also be done collectively.

In practice: you must loop in the program for the creation of groups, attributes and datasets.

The reason is that every rank must know about the whole layout of the HDF5 file.

An alternative in some cases is to write one hdf5 file per rank. In the case of fully independent groups this makes sense.

The page [Collective Calling Requirements in Parallel HDF5 Applications](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/CollectiveCalls.html) lists the routines that must be called in the "collective" mode. The requirements are the same for all APIs (C, C++, Fortran, etc).

Comment: Isn't the "file.createGroup" called in collective mode in the example above? I don't have something like `if (rank == 3) { file.createGroup(groupPath) };` in the example. Or is there some flag that I have to set to make sure that the parallel operations run in collective mode?

Comment: In your code, every rank writes its own group. In collective mode, an operation must be called/executed on every processor. This is why I mention the loop: all processors must create `RANK_GROUP0`, `RANK_GROUP1`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, understood! One more question regarding the code: how can I use the C++ interface to obtain the same result as with `H5Pset_fapl_mpio`, do you maybe know which class in the C++ API is responsible for this?

Comment: I am not familiar with the c++ API. According to 1. [the documentation for file creation property lists H5::FileCreatPropList](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/class_h5_1_1_file_creat_prop_list.html) - the equivalent of set_fapl and 2. this [mailing list message by a member of the HDF group](http://hdf-forum.184993.n3.nabble.com/HDF-with-MPI-and-CPP-td972078.html) the C++ API does not support the parallel HDF5 interface. You can use the plain C API from C++ however, which you have started to do anyway.

Comment: You might be interested by [h5xx](https://github.com/h5md/h5xx), a C++ wrapper that relies only on the C API of HDF5.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, figuring out how to use the C++ API was not leading anywhere so far.